# How does Apache Beam Fault Tolerance work for Global Windows?

Tags: apache-beam

I'm building pipeline with Beam Python. I have a stream of events coming in from PubSub with userId and buttonId. I have a global window that maintains how many times a button was clicked across all users.

If, after some time the server restarts running the Direct Runner/Flink Runner, will the global windows state be restored to the pipeline?

How does the fault tolerance in Beam work?

How does the offset/checkpoint to PubSub get tracked?

The [Beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html) states:

> Storage and fault tolerance of state: since state is per-key-and-window, the more keys and windows you expect to process simultaneously, the more storage you will incur".

However, i cannot find any more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

To the first part of your question, beam handles exceptions in a streaming service by draining, some details are covered here https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/stopping-a-pipeline

Though not sure if that answers your question on offset/checkpoint.

Comment: As I can tell at this moment in time, there is no fault tolerance built into Apache Beam to store state for global windows running on the DirectRunner, Flink, or the DataFlow Runner in Python.

Stopping A Pipeline article states: Draining a streaming pipeline that uses the Apache Beam SDK for Python is not supported. Draining batch pipelines is not supported.

I hope a resolution for this comes out soon.

Comment: Beam has since added Additional common features not yet part of the Beam model. Which documents that Drain and Checkpoint support are not really supported yet.https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/#cap-full-misc